# Turn a mouseover event into an autoscroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, parallax

As part of the creation of an overlay, I got a code that is close to what I want to do, on codepen.
This one displays a parallax of text on a background.
But on the CodePen project, the motion animation is done on a mouseover event.
I would like to make this animation happen automatically, over a period of ten seconds, without having to call a mouseover.

Here is the code in question

```js
const position = document.documentElement;
position.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  position.style.setProperty("--x", e.clientX + "px");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "poppins";
  font-weight: 900;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #111;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  transform: skewY(350deg) translateY(-200px);
  animation: animatecolor 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animatecolor {
  0% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.text h2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 8em;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: calc(var(--x)) 100px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transform: translateX(calc(0% - var(--x) * var(--i)));
}
.text h2 span {
  color: #0f0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.text h2 span:nth-child(even) {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="text">
    <a href="https://wgraphiste.com" target="blank">
      <h2 style="--i:0.5"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.5"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:2.5"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:2.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:0.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:3"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.75"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you in advance for your ideas! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be changed to run automatically with the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) like this:

```js
const position = document.documentElement;

let time = Date.now(), x = 0;

const move = () => {
  if (Date.now() - time > 10000)
    return;
  position.style.setProperty("--x", (x++) + "px");
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
};

move();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "poppins";
  font-weight: 900;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #111;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  transform: skewY(350deg) translateY(-200px);
  animation: animatecolor 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animatecolor {
  0% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.text h2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 8em;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: calc(var(--x)) 100px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transform: translateX(calc(0% - var(--x) * var(--i)));
}
.text h2 span {
  color: #0f0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.text h2 span:nth-child(even) {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="text">
    <a href="https://wgraphiste.com" target="blank">
      <h2 style="--i:0.5"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.5"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:2.5"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:2.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:0.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:3"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.25"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
      <h2 style="--i:1.75"><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span><span>WGRAPHISTE.COM</span></h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```